# Is it possible to create a new row in models.py for a list of items in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to create a todo app, and I want to have a CharField in my models.py for each todo item. Here's my code right now:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    todo = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

I want to make it so a new row in the database is created for each new todo. For example, there would be a row for one task, and another row for another task. How would I go about this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add additional model(table) for ToDo and connect it with [many-to-one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) relationship

```
Class ToDo(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      todo = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='')
```

You should probably want to read a bit more about database relationships

Comment: Thanks, I would consider myself a beginner with databases in Django so I will definitely research more into this topic.

Comment: I tried to run the code that you gave but now I am getting this error: `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'users_todo' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: users_todo.author_id contains a value 'author_id' that does not have a corresponding value in auth_user.id.`

Comment: I haven't gave you required code, just an example. Your error doesn't have anything with your primary question. It does seem you have saved row with id 1 in table with user id that does not exist.